# Is it possible to have two host identifications for a single domain?

Tags: ssh

I'm running a docker container that expects SSH traffic on port 22.  The host machine also expects SSH traffic, but on port 2222.

While SSH-ing on port 2222 works without hickups, my SSH client complains that the remote host identification has changed when SSH-ing on port 22.  This makes sense, since the docker container has a different identity than the host machine.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (not sure if the cleanest, or best) would be to copy the host keys into the container as well.

Comment: are you refering to the contents of `/etc/ssh`?   Where are said host keys stored?

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to `/etc/ssh/*host*key*`. Just keep in mind, that if the container is compromised, these keys could be used for MitM attack on the host.

Answer (score 1):

As manual pages for `sshd(8)` suggests, the known_hosts file has such syntax:

> Hostnames is a comma-separated list of patterns (‘*’ and ‘?’ act as wildcards); each pattern in turn is matched against the canonical host name (when authenticating a client) or against the user-supplied name (when authenticating a server).  A pattern may also be preceded by ‘!’ to indicate negation: if the host name matches a negated pattern, it is not accepted (by that line) even if it matched another pattern on the line.  A hostname or address may optionally be enclosed within ‘[’ and ‘]’ brackets then followed by ‘:’ and a non-standard port number.

Especially the last sentence mentioning that you can also specify non-standard port to hostname to make sure it is used for correct port. Previous solution is more obscurity ...

So editing your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file you can achieve this result.